# Express return res.send get Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I searched this error is caused by `res.send` twice. The solution should use `return res.send`.

But It doesn't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
function editFoo(req, res) {
  ErrorResponse.checkError422(req, res)
  console.log("shouldn't print")
  Foo.findAndUpdate({_id:req.params.activityId}, {$set:{title:req.body.title}}, {new: true}, function(err, activity) {
        return res.send({code: 0, newTitle: activity.title, message: "Edit successfully"})
    })
}
```

**ErrorResponse.js**

```
function checkError422(req, res) {
  const errors = validationResult(req)

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).send({error: "xxx"})
  }
}

module.exports = { checkError422 }
```

Then I got the error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

and `shouldn't print` printed.

But if I replaced `ErrorResponse.checkError422(req, res)` by the check error code directly,

```
function editFoo(req, res) {
      const errors = validationResult(req)

      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).send({error: "xxx"})
      }
      console.log("shouldn't print")
      Foo.findAndUpdate({_id:req.params.activityId}, {$set:{title:req.body.title}}, {new: true}, function(err, activity) {
            return res.send({code: 0, newTitle: activity.title, message: "Edit successfully"})
        })
    }
```

works well and not print "`shouldn't print`"

Not sure what's wrong here. I want to use `checkError422` function to replace many checks. I think the 
`return res.status(422).send({error: "xxx"})`
should exit this `editFoo`.

Why? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your code the `checkError422` can the `res` still send an answer... so You have to do the inverse...

```
  // checkError422
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).send({error: "xxx"})
  }
```

---

So :

```
function editFoo(req, res) {
      const errors = validationResult(req)

      if (errors.isEmpty()) {
           console.log("shouldn't print")
           Foo.findAndUpdate({_id:req.params.activityId}, {$set:{title:req.body.title}}, {new: true}, function(err, activity) {
                return res.send({code: 0, newTitle: activity.title, message: "Edit successfully"})
           })
      }
    }
```

---

**Update**

your code is redondant, so you just have to do :

```
function checkError422(req, res) {
  return validationResult(req)
}

module.exports = { checkError422 }
```

Comment: I want to return errors also. And not sure why `checkError422` not exit the function with `return res.send...`?